# /usr/ucb/cc: language optional software package not installed

Tags: solaris, c

I tried to compile some C code to get object file from a shell prompt:

```
$cc a.c
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
/usr/ucb/cc:  language optional software package not installed
```

How can I compile C code?

Comment: What version of Solaris? Copy-paste the output of `uname -a`. Either you don't have a compiler or it's not in the default `PATH`; ask your admins. If you don't have a Sun compiler (or even if you have one), you can install GCC, possibly from a Sun software distribution.

Answer (score 9):

First, you should remove `/usr/ucb` from your PATH as this directory is quite obsolete now. It was meant to ease people migrating from SunOS 4 to Solaris 2 a couple of decades ago but doesn't make much sense these days. Especially this `cc` commands which set specific flags to compile BSDish code.

Second, all current Solaris releases come with a C compiler out of the box but it is located in a directory which might not be in your `PATH`, `/usr/sfw/bin` and is named `gcc` (Gnu compiler). Note that Solaris 11 has `gcc` in the `PATH`.

On Solaris 10, use

```
/usr/sfw/bin/gcc
```

or

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/sfw/bin
gcc
```

Alternatively, you might have already installed (or [you can install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194196/2594)) the Solaris Studio compiler (now Oracle Developer Studio). In that case, its path would be `<installation-dir>/bin/cc` (eg: `/opt/SUNWspro/bin/cc, /opt/SolarisStudio11/bin/cc`, `/opt/OracleDeveloperStudio12.5-OS-sparc-bin-bin/developerstudio12.5/bin/cc`, etc.)

Comment: How do we install the Sun Studio compiler rather than using GCC. We catch occasional bug reports for SunCC, but a fresh install of Solaris 10 only produces the message discussed in the question. For completeness, we are OK with the gear for Sun Studio 12.2 and above; we need Sun Studio on Solaris 10. Also see [How to find past downloads after "Sun Download Center Changes"](http://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.unix.solaris/F6SJ4NxIoFE/A0dqOL2GCwAJ)

Comment: @jww Isn't this already answered here http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194196/2594 ?

Comment: Thanks Jlliagre. That's Sun Studio 12.5. Were interested in Sun Studio for Solaris 10. The cited answer and its link if for Sun Studio 12.5, which is for Solaris 11.

Comment: @jww Not only Solaris 11. There are download links for Oracle Solaris 10 (SPARC and x86) SVR4 installers.

Comment: Thanks again Jlliagre. [How to find past downloads after "Sun Download Center Changes"](http://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.unix.solaris/F6SJ4NxIoFE/A0dqOL2GCwAJ) states its effectively one of the those dead-end webmaster loops that results in a non-download. Its very frustrating.

Comment: @jww Do you mean you are unable to download either of these Solaris 10 tarballs?

Answer (score 2):

It is unfortunate that sun ever shipped /usr/ucb/cc; you would think
it was compatible with SunOS 4; instead it compatible with some very
old version of 4.2 but it also required the installation of the
SunPro (Now Solaris Studio) compilers.

These compilers can be downloaded from

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/downloads/index.html

under the following license terms (quoted from the above page)

Provides perpetual no-cost license for production use and the development of commercial applications.

Answer (score 1):

Your Solaris installation doesn't have a compiler installed.
Back in the 1900:s, Sun charged extra for their C compiler, and provided a stub "cc" command instead, just to remind you that the compiler is not installed.

To compile a file, you need to install a compiler for the same Solaris version (2.5.1?) and architecture (SPARC/sun4m?) that matches your operating system and computer hardware.

Read more at [SunFreeware.com](http://www.sunfreeware.com/) for free software that installs under /usr/local/.

If you take that open source/GNU road, you will probably need to install a lot of packages to satisfy dependencies before it works, but if you have the disk space it would probably be worth it.

Old versions of Sun's SparCompiler/Forte/SunStudio can be hard to obtain for your (supposedly) old machine, as they were typically licensed with node locked licenses, and you will not be able to buy a license for those obsoleted software packages any more.

Comment: This cc isn't a stub command to remind the compiler is not installed but was designed to ease recompiling code written for SunOS 4 (BSD) on Solaris 2 (System V).

Comment: /usr/ucb/cc: language optional software package not installed

Comment: It does indeed report that situation but my point was /usr/ucb/cc isn't "just a stub command designed to remind the compiler isn't installed" but a command with a different and specific purpose.